# Using pandoc's slidy offline

Tags: slideshow, offline, pandoc

I'm using Pandoc to convert from Markdown to the Slidy slideshow format. But I need to use slidy offline so I put a copy of the slidy script that I downloaded from their site http://www.w3.org/Talks/Tools/Slidy2/slidy.zip under a folder "Slidy2" then I use the command

```
 pandoc -s -t slidy -V slidy-url=Slidy2
```

to link my local copy of slidy, pandoc generates the following html code

```
...
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
  <meta name="generator" content="pandoc" />
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">code{white-space: pre;}</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection, print"
    href="Slidy2/styles/slidy.css" />
<script src="Slidy2/scripts/slidy.js.gz"
    charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
...
```

but slidy is not working at all.

in the slidy page the following the following options are mentioned:

```
1. Use relative URIs depending on your local setup to access the appropriate files. 
   Use the same directory structure as on the W3C server, ie, ".../2005/Talks/...".

2. Run a Web server on your machine so that the directory above can be accessed via
   http://localhost/Talks/Tools/Slidy2 and use the URIs of the form   
   "/Talks/Tools/Slidy2/styles/slidy.css", "/Talks/Tools/Slidy2/scripts/slidy.js".
```

I don't know what could it be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what was the problem but changing the line that load the compressed version of the slidy script `src="Slidy2/scripts/slidy.js.gz"` to the uncompressed version `src="Slidy2/scripts/slidy.js"` solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the --self-contained option to generate a self-sufficient HTML code. Your HTML code is not complete. It is missing `<html>, <body>` elements

Comment: I din't paste all the html code, only the part with the link to slidy.  I have a problem with --self-contained because --mathjax doesn't work.